# Scanner no deja escribir nada

Tags: java, scanner

Encontré un ejemplo de un código utilizando Scanner y quise probarlo, pero me sucede que cuando el Scanner debería de pedirme los datos, no lo hace. Simplemente no me deja escribir nada. Busqué soluciones pero no hallé nada y no sé si es que tal vez estoy haciendo algo mal.
Este es el código, btw

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class test{
public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Ingresa tu nombre");
String nombre = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Hola " + nombre);
}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probé otros códigos que encontré y el Scanner no me funciona con ninguno, o sea, no puedo introducir datos, escribo pero no aparece nada. ¿Cuál podría ser la razón?

Comment: yo veo que tu codigo esta bien y ademas me funciona, lo que no especificas es si realmente te compila si no, es ahi el problema, y el programa nunca corre. Saludos.[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T70MU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T70MU.png)

Comment: Prueba con: nombre = sc.next();

Comment: Me parece que es otro el problema y no el codigo, que version de NetBeans estas usando?

Comment: @Jorgesys lo probé utilizando la versión 12.4 y luego también lo he probado en la 12.5 y nada, sigue sin funcionarme